# Не прослушивается событие внутри тултипа (tippy.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Я хочу сделать меню на внешнем сайте, в котором я смогу нажимать кнопки.
Проблема в том, что кнопки я в нем нажимать не могу.
Делал при помощи tippy.js и tampermonkey.

Проблема в том, что tippy.js добавляет свой тултип в html после того, как я непосредстсвенно его вызываю.

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки внутри данного тултипа происходило действие (записывался текст в textarea), но никак прослушать событие я не могу. Вернее, могу, но оно дублируется.

Пытался делать `onclick` у кнопки, `$('#answers_0').bind('click', ...)` когда вызывается `onShown()` у экземпляра тултипа, но оно дублируется, даже после `$('#answers_0').unbind('click')`

```js
    'use strict';
    var container = document.querySelector('#content > div > div > div > div.chat.chat-float > div.chat-form > form');
    var clip = document.querySelector('#content > div > div > div > div.chat.chat-float > div.chat-form > form > div.chat-form-btn');
    var button = document.createElement('div');
    button.className = 'chat-form-attach';
    button.innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="cutButton" class="btn btn-default chat-btn-image"><i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i></i></button>'
    container.insertBefore(button, clip);

    var answers = [{name: '123', text: 'test'}];

    tippy('#cutButton', {
        content: `<div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" value="" checked>
    <label for="tab-btn-1">Ответы</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2" value="">
    <label for="tab-btn-2 ml-auto">Парсинг</label>

  <div id="content-1">
<ul class="list-group overflow-auto">`
        + answers.map((el, index) => {return '<li class="list-group-item" id="answer_' + index + '">' + el.name + '</li>'}) +
        `</ul>
  </div>
  <div id="content-2">
    Содержимое 2...
  </div>
</div>`,
        allowHTML: true,
        interactive: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        moveTransition: 'transform 0.2s ease-out',

    });

    //--- Activate the newly added button.
    document.getElementById ("cutButton").addEventListener (
        "click", ButtonClickAction, false
    );

    function sendAnswer (text) {
        //$('#comments > textarea').val(text);
        console.log(text);
    }

    function ButtonClickAction (zEvent) {
        console.log('click!');
    }
```

Пробовал такой вариант:

```js
tippy('...', {
  content :`...`,
  onShown() {
    answers.map((el, index) => {
      $('#answer_' + index).bind('click', () => {return sendAnswer(el.text)});
    })
  },
  onHidden() {
    answers.map((el, index) => {
      $('#answer_' + index).unbind('click');
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: "но оно дублируется" - ??

Comment: @Igor `$(...).unbind()` не выполняется при `onHidden()`

Comment: в коде вопроса нет ни `.unbind()`, ни `onHidden()`

Comment: @Igor Добавил код

Answer (score 2):

Это `id`?

```
$('#answer_' + index)
   ^
```

Comment: Я забыл указать это в коде, но это было написано правильно (`$('#answer_' + index).unbind(...)`). Смысл в том, что в функции sendAnswer я банально поставиль вывод события в консоль, и [вот, что получил](https://imgur.com/a/FUYFnnK) при повторном открытии меню и нажатии на одну кнопку